# "The obvious choice was" or "the obvious choice were"?

Tags: grammar, verbs

Which is correct?

> The obvious choice was posters.

Or

> The obvious choice were posters.

I'm confused because "obvious choice" is singular. On the other hand, the actual choice is plural (posters).

I did [two](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1855&bih=954&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk03pshX8dXPoPb6r0tXA6DG-V57I4g%3A1582636887610&ei=Vx9VXpDoJMeC-QaE6ITAAg&q=%22%20the%20obvious%20choice%20was%20%22&oq=%22%20the%20obvious%20choice%20was%20%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1195.2907.0.3013.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.CW_Rn-BV3gs) Google Book [searches](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1855&bih=954&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk01ZU9tKCYFf0FZp5TH4TsqZiHg3gg%3A1582636891756&ei=Wx9VXpzgLdXrwQOZnYiwAQ&q=%22%20the%20obvious%20choice%20were%20%22&oq=%22%20the%20obvious%20choice%20were%20%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...82253.82950.0.83330.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.6_wd8oW5R9w). But since I got results for both, I couldn't figure out which is the correct option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just bank on reliable dictionaries, and not books.
According to Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English and OALD, choice can be a countable or uncountable noun.

> Voters have a choice between three main political parties. (Countable)
>   He has to make some important choices.   (Countable)
>   We had no choice but to destroy the animal. (uncountable)

then

> The obvious choice was posters.

Answer (score 2):

> The obvious choice was posters.

Obviously, someone made one choice (to choose the posters) and no matter how many choices and how many posters were available, the final choice was one choice.